# Use context inside a class which extends a state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I want to show a welcome screen and after the last item I want to show a button an redirect the user to a certian page. Unfortunately I got an error:

`The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`.

What is the best option to use `context` inside the `_WelcomeScreenState` class?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '/items.dart';
import '/SecondRoute.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {

  List<Widget> slides = items
      .map((item) => Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Image.asset(
              item['image'],
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: 220.0,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(item['header'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 50.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Color(0XFF3F3D56),
                          height: 2.0)),
                  Text(
                    item['description'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        letterSpacing: 1.2,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        height: 1.3),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  if (item.containsKey('button') && item['button'] == 'true')
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Open route'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )))
      .toList();

  List<Widget> indicator() => List<Widget>.generate(
      slides.length,
          (index) => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
        height: 10.0,
        width: 10.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: currentPage.round() == index
                ? Color(0XFF256075)
                : Color(0XFF256075).withOpacity(0.2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      ));

  double currentPage = 0.0;
  final _pageViewController = new PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageViewController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = _pageViewController.page!;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView.builder(
              controller: _pageViewController,
              itemCount: slides.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return slides[index];
              },
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: indicator(),
                  ),
                )
              //  ),
            )
            // )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your slides inside [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) or (i think it's a better approach) build your layout inside the build method from the items array or (i think it's the best) make a new Item widget and instantiate in build method.

**Example 1:**

```
@override
void initState() {

  super.initState();

  slides = items.map((item) => Container(
    ...
  ).toList();

  _pageViewController.addListener(() {
    setState(() {
    currentPage = _pageViewController.page!;
  });
}
```

**Example 2 (better):**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView.builder(
          controller: _pageViewController,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(...use  items[index] to access the current item, or you can write a builder method and call it here to keep this part simple...);
          },
        ),
        ...
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

**Example 3 best:**

```
class SlideWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final ItemClass item;

  const SlideWidget({Key? key,required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(...);
  }
}
```

And inside your WelcomeScreen:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView.builder(
          controller: _pageViewController,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return SlideWidget(item: items[index]);
          },
        ),
        ...
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show me the complete code?

Comment: With "Example 3" just copy your Slider layout code inside the SlideWidget build method (I don't know your item object class so replace "ItemClass" with your class name) and replace the PageView.builder inside your WelcomeScreen with my example code and you are done. (The full code is more than the comment allowed character count)